# What else is included in XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I've been using XAMPP, but want to switch to a full 64-Bit Windows web platform with PHP 7. I know I will need to install the 64-bit versions of Apache, MySQL and PHP. but what else?

For instance, with XAMPP SSL support just worked right out of the box. I presume I'll need to sort out OpenSSL. What about OpenSSL for PHP? Again, out of the box I can just use those functions in PHP, but is OpenSSL in the standard Windows PHP package?

I'm curious about the above and anything else I might not have thought of.

Comment: Email (IMAP/POP/SMTP/...), FTP (FTP/FTPS/...), Database (MySQL). And OpenSSL is not part of PHP but of XAMPP, used for HTTPS and other protocols. Btw.: what do you think belongs to "a full 64-Bit Windows web platform" that is not included with XAMPP?

Comment: All time better - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP

Comment: @hherger well mainly 64-bit versions of Apache, MySQL and PHP (XAMPP uses 32 bit versions of them). I presume a live web server will certainly want at least Apache running 64-bit for the larger memory pool.

Comment: Yes, for Windows the 32-bit variants are included. You could try to compile Apache, and the modules (PHP) from source, if your situation really requires it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from xampp website: Includes: Apache 2.4.17, MariaDB 10.1.9, PHP 5.5.30, phpMyAdmin 4.5.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1, XAMPP Control Panel 3.2.1, Webalizer 2.23-04, Mercury Mail Transport System 4.63, FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41, Tomcat 7.0.56 (with mod_proxy_ajp as connector), Strawberry Perl 7.0.56 Portable

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: What about PHP extensions? Just OpenSSL?

Comment: Easiest way to know your extensions is to make a file called info.php with the following code: <?php phpinfo(); ?> and then access info.php in your browser